# how to pass src as parameter in url in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to react JS, in my program I have three CARDS,
for these cards I have created separate component. for each CARD I want to pass the image URL as well may,
I know how can I do this. Please help me on this. 
-----------------------------
**CARD COMPONENT**
-----------------------------

```
import React from "react";

const Card = ({CardTitle="Football", CardTxt="Nothing", ImgURL="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3532544/pexels-photo-3532544.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500") => (
  <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
    <img
      src={{ImgURL}}
      className="card-img-top"
      alt="..."
    />
    <div className="card-body">
<h5 className="card-title">{CardTitle}</h5>
      <p className="card-text">{CardTxt}
      </p>
      <a href="#" className="btn btn-success">
        Go somewhere
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Card;
```

-----------------------------
**CARDSECTION COMPONENT**
-----------------------------

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card";


const CardSection = () => (
  <section className="contact bg-success ">
    <div className="container ">
      <h2 className="text-white">We love new friends!</h2>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-4">
          <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3532557/pexels-photo-3532557.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
              className="card-img-top"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p className="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" className="btn btn-success">
                Go somewhere
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-4">
          <Card CardTitle="Hello World" CardTxt="Inside a React component that needs URL path data, this is the code you’ll"/>
        </div>
        <div className="col-4">
          <div className="card" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
            <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2522663/pexels-photo-2522663.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
              className="card-img-top"
              alt="..."
            />
            <div className="card-body">
              <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p className="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                the bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" className="btn btn-success">
                Go somewhere
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
);

export default CardSection;
```

-----------------------------
**CARD TAG**
-----------------------------

```
<div className="col-4">
          <Card CardTitle="Hello World" CardTxt="Inside a React component that needs URL path data, this is the code you’ll"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: You probably need https://github.com/ljharb/qs this lib to get params from url

Comment: Here you can find the example with react-router https://medium.com/better-programming/using-url-parameters-and-query-strings-with-react-router-fffdcea7a8e9